# Facebook IOS SDK Feed Post Visibility

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, fbconnect

I have this function

```
-(void)feed_post:(NSString *)message andDelegate:(id<FBRequestDelegate>)delegate{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   message, @"message",
                                   nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:delegate];

}
```

to post a message to the user's wall. Everything is working but the post is only visible by me. It seems that it is posting as an own private message. How should I configure the params to change the post visibility? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick. Also I had to delete cookies.

```
NSDictionary *dictPrivacy = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"EVERYONE",@"value", nil];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSString *strPrivacy = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:dictPrivacy];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   message, @"message",
                                   strPrivacy,@"privacy",
                                   nil];
```

Comment: I just had the opposite problem - I wanted to test whether my app was posting correctly, without everyone else seeing. Based on the code above, use: `NSString *strPrivacy = @"{'value': 'SELF'}";`